# Embedding flash within a custom desktop application, using NPAPI?

Tags: flash, plugins, npapi

Note: Please don't answer with *just use Adobe AIR*". I am aware of it, and it's not applicable in this situation.

I've been reviewing the [Gecko Plugin API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference).

I'm assuming I'd have to implement all the required browser-side functionality. My goal is to be able to access the graphical output of Flash at a low level, in order to integrate them into an application, along with other native code. Adobe AIR is a future possibility but performance is nowhere near good enough yet for this project.

Does anyone know of an open-source project which acts as a NPAPI plugin host? I suppose alternatives are to extract the necessary bits from WebKit, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, check out ScreenweaverHX:

http://haxe.org/com/libs/swhx

http://code.google.com/p/screenweaver-hx/

HTH

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! 
Of specific interest to my question was this file:

http://code.google.com/p/screenweaver-hx/source/browse/trunk/src/np_host.c

Comment: Can you share simple example howto host flash in standalone aplications? It will be very greate. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

nspluginwrapper implements browser-side npapi to make a proxy allowing 32-bit plugins to be used in 64-bit browser, and has fewer lines of code than a browser, could be a good starting point if you want to implement it.

also maybe unrelated but aiming at similar environment is chromeless, a derivative of Firefox which is a lightweight browser which doesn't have an interface, useful to make a desktop app out of html, javascript and plugins.