# How to embed a flash player in a GTK app?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, flash, embedded-flashplayer

has anyone tried to embed a Adobes FlashPlayer into a `c`-written `Gtk`-Application?

Is it possible? Are there any good points to start?

P.S.: I do not want to embed the `WebKit` or `Gecko` renderengine into my application!

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643177

Comment: no dup. i do not want to use gecko and screenweaver does not work on linux yet. (but that is somethink i like to change!)

Comment: As the comment to the answer on that question notes, you just want to implement what http://code.google.com/p/screenweaver-hx/source/browse/trunk/src/np_host.c does.

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer have a flash plugin. Also Gnash and klash are free swf players. You can start from this applications. The code is free for use :)

Regards