# Can SWFs be integrated in a Java application?

Tags: flash

I'm looking to embed SWF files into a Java program, but I'm having trouble finding the way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do probably involves embedding somehow the Flash player in your app. See these two:

[Embedding flash within a custom desktop application, using NPAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643177/embedding-flash-within-a-custom-desktop-application-using-npapi/645701)

[Embedding Flash Player in a C++ or Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214411/embedding-flash-player-in-a-c-or-java-application/741518)

Be aware of licensing issues if you plan to redistribute the player. Take a look to the [Open Screen Project](http://www.openscreenproject.org/).

Good luck