# Use official flash plugin to present a swf file

Tags: browser, adobe, flash, browser-plugin

I want to show a flash file (.swf) in my executable program on Windows.

Every single modern browser are able to do it by using the official flash plugin DLL by Adobe. But there's no documentation anywhere of HOW you do it!

For years I've searched high and low on the Internet for an answer to HOW DO YOU USE THE OFFICIAL FLASH PLAYER PLUGIN IN YOUR PROGRAMS?

Programming language doesn't matter, I can adapt. I just want instructions on how to do it. Links to hidden resources on the web or your own expertise. Say I make a program that uses OpenGL, I want to send the binary of a swf file to the flash plugin, get data back and then render it using OpenGL. But how? How do browsers do it? **How how how???**

Comment: this question may be better suited to http://superuser.com/

Comment: OK sure, I've added it there too: http://superuser.com/questions/554021/use-official-flash-plugin-to-present-a-swf-file

Comment: i know it used to be possible to embed (and control) flash inside a visual basic application - that was a long time ago though...

Comment: Code can be timeless sometimes, even if it was long ago I'd love to get info on it. The question on superuser was closed due to being offtopic btw. I knew it :/

Comment: What platform, programming language, ... ? Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214411/embedding-flash-player-in-a-c-or-java-application) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks but tried that already in the past. It goes black when the user is not present (when the screen is locked).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... if you are using .NET... use the ActiveX dll and create an activeX object, then load the swf file within that container.

Cheers.

Comment: I mean I know I should use the flash plugin dll and that it would be good to load it in some container in my code... but how?

Comment: I'm still looking for the answer to this question: How?